# Showing both Toolbar and TabLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using this xml to hide the Appbar on scrolling down it's working fine but I want to show toolbar and TabLayout both on scrolling up currently it is showing only TabLayout.

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 >

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

  <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_size_big"
      app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
      >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleMarginTop="15dp"
        />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:tabContentStart="150dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTheme"
        custom:tabGravity="fill"
        />

  </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

[Currently getting something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKeXr.png)
[image: I want Some Thing Like this]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have already added `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` for `TabLayout`. Do the same for `Toolbar`. And remove `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Comment: And what happens, when you remove `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Comment: If I remove CollapsingToolbarLayout the then I will not be able to set the appbar height

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding below line to your `Toolbar`.

```
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

As per mentioned in **Collapsing Toolbars** section in [Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html), 
use CollapsingToolbarLayout’s `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` to ensure that the Toolbar itself remains pinned to the top of the screen while the view collapses.

Comment: It will overlap the Toolbar and Tablayout

Comment: Try with taking `Tablayout` outside of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and inside of `AppBarLayout`

Comment: Try wiht using `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Checkout example xml here https://gist.github.com/SaitejaP/20f8104ec7ab113e0f8a